# Inverse Laplace transformation - Bessel function

Tags: laplace-transform

How to find $f$ using Laplace transformation?

$f = J_0 * J_0$ where * is a convolution. According to the Convolution theorem it is $$(J_0 * J_0)(t):= \int_0^t J_0 (t - \tau) J_0 (\tau)\mathop{\mathrm d \tau}$$

$$J_\nu(z)=\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^\nu\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!\Gamma(\nu+k+1)}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2k}$$

**EDIT**
Please, can you explain me the equality in the picture?
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH2kR.png) And I do not understant why (2m)! is divided by $s^{2m+1}$. There is used Laplace transform of $t^{\alpha}$? Why?

Comment: Bessel function

Comment: That is Laplace of $x^{2m}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$${\cal L}(J_0*J_0)={\cal L}^2(J_0)=\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}\right)^2=\dfrac{1}{s^2+1}$$

Comment: The result should be sin (t). This is the Laplace transform of J_0 and I thought is it function f. So I am realy confuse how to find f?

Comment: $f$ is $\sin t$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, $ f = \sin (t)$. So I should do inverse Laplace transformation afer your hint?

Comment: Yes, simply ${\cal L}^{-1}\dfrac{1}{s^2+1}=\sin t$. What is $\cos2x$ in the title?

Comment: Thank you I add a  edit in my question.